# Unwanted padding and unable to set Height for the print in thermal printer in Flutter

Tags: flutter, printing, padding, thermal-printer

In my flutter project I need to print a receipt through Bluetooth thermal printer and its working perfectly but the receipt I am getting is having unwanted padding at start and end of the content and I am not able to set the height to it. Here's sharing code below:

```
Future<void> printTicket(
  ) async {
String? isConnected = await BluetoothThermalPrinter.connectionStatus;
print('printing connection status');

print(isConnected);
if (isConnected == "true") {
  final List<int> bytes = await thermalPrint();
  await BluetoothThermalPrinter.writeBytes(bytes);
  
} else {
  await BluetoothThermalPrinter.connect(
      bluetoothBox.get('printerCredentials')['macAddr']);
  final List<int> bytes = await thermalPrint();
  await BluetoothThermalPrinter.writeBytes(bytes);
  //Hadnle Not Connected Senario
}
```

}

```
 Future<List<int>> thermalPrint() async {
List<int> bytes = [];
CapabilityProfile profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
final generator = Generator(PaperSize.mm58, profile);

final imageBytes = await generateImageFromString();

img.Image image = img.decodeImage(imageBytes) as img.Image;

bytes += generator.image(image, align: PosAlign.right);
bytes += generator.cut();
return bytes;
```

}

and

```
 Future<Uint8List> generateImageFromString() async {
print(_collectionItem.session);
ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
Canvas canvas = Canvas(recorder, Rect.largest);

TextSpan span = TextSpan(
  children: <TextSpan>[
    TextSpan(text: "Printing Test",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24),)
   
  ],
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 22,
    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
  ),
);
TextPainter tp = TextPainter(
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    text: span,
    textDirection: ui.TextDirection.ltr);
tp.layout(
  minWidth: 400,
  maxWidth: 400,
);
tp.paint(canvas, Offset(0, 0.0));
final picture = recorder.endRecording();
final pngBytes = await picture.toImage(
  tp.size.width.toInt(),
  tp.size.height.toInt(),
);
final byteData = await pngBytes.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
return byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
```

}

Here is the image results as well
[image: Marked the extra space here]